# Caching not working on Parse

Tags: android, caching, parse-platform

I tried to cache the query but the Parse is causing [it](http://pastebin.com/rZux4f8d), the source code is [here](http://pastebin.com/KryWRjQz).

A snippet(the principal):

```
@Override
    protected ArrayList<Feed> doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
        page = integers[0];
        ArrayList<Feed> backgroundItems = new ArrayList<Feed>();
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("FeedPost");
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
        query.setLimit(displayLimit);//Aqui o limite da 5
        query.setSkip(page * displayLimit);
        try {
            responseList = query.find();
            ParseObject.pinAll(FINAL_FEED_CACHE, responseList); //Error happens here
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            for (int i = 0; i < responseList.size(); i++) {
                ParseObject parseObject = responseList.get(i);
                backgroundItems.add(new Feed(parseObject.getObjectId(),
                        parseObject.getString("Title"),
                        parseObject.getString("Description"),
                        parseObject.getString("CompleteText"),
                        parseObject.getString("imageURL"),
                        parseObject.getString("Link_on_Site")));
            }
        return backgroundItems;
    }
```

Comment: is responseList null?

Comment: no. backgroundItems and responseList isn't empty.